# How can I slide a string out to the left, replace the text with next element in array, and slide back in place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hBSdf/).

I need a sentence to slide out to the left (out of view), change text to next line in story (next element in array) and slide back right, into place.

Also, I need to be able to have the whole thing repeat, but I expect that's just a matter of resetting `i` in the loop.

Can you help me?

HTML:

```
​<p class="wrap"><span>Foo</span></p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
var stringArr = ['One','Two','Three'],
    i = 0,
    t = 2000;

for ( i ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    $('.wrap span').delay(t).animate({'left': '+=200px'}, 'slow');
    $('.wrap span').text(stringArr[i]).appendTo($('.wrap span'));
    $('.wrap span').animate({'right': '+=200px'}, 'slow');
}​
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it simply by animating the `left` property of a positioned container:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>​
```

with the following CSS (note `position: relative` for the slider):

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: #ffbbbb;
    width: 200px;
}

#slider {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
}
```

This is [the script I used in my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2x3SG/1/):

```
var strings = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen".split(" "),
    offset = 0,
    delay = 1500,
    slider = $("#slider");

var swap = function(element, strings, offset) {
    element.text(strings[(offset++) % strings.length]);
    element.animate({"left": "0%"});
    element.delay(delay).animate({"left": "-100%"});
    element.queue(function(next) {
        swap(element, strings, offset);
        next();
    });
}

swap(slider, strings, offset);
```

Comment: This ran smooth from the start.  Well done.  Thanks.  I've transfered my animation strategy to this one instead.  Care to share now what you see wrong with `setInterval()`?

Comment: Basically, whenever you pass a *delay* to an API, you should really consider it a *hint*: the environment (browser, virtual machine, or OS) will do its best to execute the callback as soon as the delay expires, but in a multiprocess context there can be no guarantee about *when* your function will actually be called - on a busy machine two or more calls may overlap and cause glitches. When this sort of synchronization is needed you'd better rely on a clock, or put your code in a loop. In this case I used a callback

Answer (score 2):

```
var stringArr = ['One','Two','Three'],
    i = 0,
    t = 2000,
    initialDelay = 150,
    container = $(".wrap span"),
    len = stringArr.length,
    changer = function() {
        var step = (++i)%len;

        container.animate({'left': '+=200px'}, 'slow', function(){
            container.text(stringArr[step]).animate({left: '-=200px'}, 'slow');
        })


    },
    interval, stop = function(){
       interval = interval !== undefined && clearInterval(interval); 
    }, start = function() {
        stop();
        interval = setInterval(changer, t);
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
        changer();
        start();
    }, initialDelay);
```

​

1. You need to specify `position` for span otherwise `left` property won't affect it.
2. You can't append a node to itself. `$("selector").appendTo($("selector"))` throws dom exception.
3. You shouldn't animate left and right properties at the same time. It will stretch your element.

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/hBSdf/10/

Comment: It doesn't really work as intended. Also, `setInterval()` is a wrong choice here because there is no guarantee on the function start/end times, so you'll end up with glitches when two or more animations overlap. You can easily experience it with a smaller `t` and a slower animation. The solution here is using callbacks or a queue

Comment: I notice the first time the page loads the animation looks choppy, but then it's fine.  Any way to delay the start so that it looks great the first time?  Also, how can I turn off the loop?

Comment: @Ryan: check my edit. Use `initalDelay` for later start, and `stop, start` functions to relaunch changing.

Comment: @Raffaele: Actually it works. `setInterval` is precise enough provided that you are not going to win an oscar for best animation.  :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko don't know, maybe you improved the code but didn't update the fiddle - still doesn't work, neither on page load nor after you click "start": the slider doesn't even slide offscreen. If it worked, I'd be able to show you what's wrong with `setInterval()` even if you don't plan to win an Oscar :)

Answer (score 0):

Still playing around with it but couple of things to start you off.

The [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function in jQuery requires a CSS Map, specifically a `position` field or else it won't really work. You can see for yourself. I don't really know why exactly so if someone wants to jump in and explain why please do ><... to be more specific in the documentation it says:

> The only required parameter is a map of CSS properties. This map is similar to the one that can be sent to the .css() method, except that the range of properties is more restrictive.

Another idea you want is use a callback so that once your animation completes, it can change the word, and then maybe move it back in place. I don't think the `delay` function is wrong but it is a lot less dynamic and if you are supposedly making a book, it'd be nice if the program just knew to do something after something was completed. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2uxSX/) is a Fiddle. Maybe when I wake up I'll add some more/edit my answer but just something to get you started/thinking :)